# How can I meet NEC code for Class 2 at the power supply with multiple strips of LED lighting?

Tags: lighting, code-compliance, led, low-voltage

**...The Project...**

Install 94 feet of perimeter lighting around a kitchen/dining/living space. The desired product is a color tunable LED strip. Possibly [this product](https://store.waveformlighting.com/collections/led-strips/products/filmgrade-hybrid-led-strip-lights) but I could use an equivalent product if needed. These things come in 16 foot lengths. So I need 6 strips to cover the installation.

**Wiring**

I have roughed in seven 16/4 CL2 rated wire to the top of the wall at locations where each 16 foot strip would start. The led strip product indicates that two strips can be chained together, but that seems like a voltage drop risk, so I ran a separate wire for each strip.

**PWM Dimming**

High frequency > 25kHz PWM dimmers are the only acceptable option for this requirement. We tested the 500hz LED dimmers and they had noticeable flicker at low light levels. There are several DMX decoders that meet this need. For example, [this product](https://store.waveformlighting.com/collections/power-supplies-and-dimmers/products/filmgrade-dmx-led-dimmer-decoder-with-5-channel-output).

**Power Supply**

Here is where the going gets tough. How do you meet class 2 power supply requirements for the installation of these products? NEC 725.121 "Power Sources for Class 2 and Class 3 Circuits" seems to require a listed class 2 power supply. Does that mean I need six separate class 2 power supplies, and six separate DMX decoders... One for each strip? That seems wasteful as a single DMX decoder is capable of 8 amps per channel and could power the entire set of 6 strips by itself.

Are there any other options for a compliant installation?

[image]

**Note** The (4) and (5) options of 725.121 are Information Equipment, and a dry cell battery. Neither of which meet this need.

Comment: 725.41 is class 1  at least in the 2017 & 2020 code class 1= 30v 1000va or less that would be a max of 33 amps.  I think I remember landscape lighting 12v limited to 25 amp. Could you double check that is the issue you are looking at.

Comment: @EdBeal I think I was looking at some old code blogs... you are correct. The area in 2017 code is 725.121. I have edited the post.

Comment: About 10 times the price I'm used to seeing for an LED strip. Might be worth it if UL listed. Why /4 wire? The strip has 3 conductors.  You don't need seven "home-runs" if you can tie to the wire. You could do with as few as three tie points, between strips 2-3, strips 4-5, and strips 6-1, and feed each strip from opposite directions. In fact this would be better to assure no visible effects of voltage drop.  *This advice applies to 24V strips. For 12V strips I'd feed every strip from both ends*. Also you know this is 23A worth of strips, right? Dimming that takes planning.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The strips are fairly high quality. If you know of any >95CRI color tunable strips pushing over 400 lumens per foot let me know! I could only find a few options and they were all about the same price. This particular product is not UL listed. I used 16/4 because it was readily available in CL2 rated form. The "home-runs" are already installed. They are overkill but offer flexibility in zoning. Many single DMX controllers can handle dimmer the entire set.... My concern is being outside of class 2 code on the power supply end.

Comment: @AnthonyVito -- have you checked Table 11(B) in Chapter 9 of the NEC?  That's where the limits on what a listed Class 2 supply can put out are found

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes. The amp limits for a class 2 supply are 100 / vMax. ( so like 100 watts ) I mentioned that a "Brute Force" solution here would be to use (6) class 2 power supplies, and (6) PWM dimmers. That would completely isolate each LED strip and comply to class 2. It's just not very economical, or scalable.

Comment: I was amazed *any* LED makes 95 CRI, so color me impressed.  The problem with seven homeruns is your voltage drop is sawtooth: 123456123456123456123456. and a very obvious difference in brightness at the transition point.   If you power from every other end, then it's 123456654321123456654321,  see what I mean? Much harder to see.  Normally I'd say use all 7 feeds and power all strips from both ends, but you probably won't need it at 24V.  Your specced dimmer looks like a good'un, but 8A output puts it a bit shy of powering every strip. You could extend with any bog-standard amplifier.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Ahhh yes... that could be a visual improvement. Great idea! I can still do that with the home-runs I have.... Just split the strips and power them all from the middle. ( The runs are placed at the 16 foot measured end of each strip ) The dimmer is spec'd at 8A per channel, with 40A total on 5 channels. That is the issue. If a single wire is connected to a driver that can put 8A on the line, then it's not class 2 anymore.....

Comment: if you connect one end of the strip's ground, and the other end's positive, the varying resistances on each pole along the way cancel each other out to self-balance brightness. A circuit that long can have significant capacitance from the strips, which complicate 25khz pwm, resulting in pwm non-linearity (lower resolution on the dim end), more heat, and lower driver performance/efficiency. Capacitance also converts the square wave to a sin-like wave, making flicker MUCH less noticeable, so if your test indicating 25k was on a short run, try a lower frequency on long run; 5khz should be plenty.

Comment: @dandavis No run is longer than 5m. If needed I could drive the strips from the center, making each run only 2.5m. The 25kHz test is one that worked, and we want that. It is the 500Hz test that failed and produced noticeable flickering at lower light levels.